# Restore warnings for file system (boot volume full)

Tags: disk-usage, notification

I accidentally hid a class of error messages from appearing again and I would like to unhide them.

I received the message:

```
The volume “boot” has only ….. bytes disk space remaining
```

while installing updates. I removed some old kernels and then dismissed the message but realised that I had accidentally selected:

'Don't show any warnings again for this file system'

I do want to get these warning messages again. How can I turn them back on?

Comment: Related [How do I enable low disk storage warnings?](//askubuntu.com/q/750912)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the `dconf-editor` (you may need to install this first). Open the key called `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.housekeeping`  (or search for "Disk Space").

Check the "active" box if it is not already active; or, if relevant, remove the path or partition from the `ignore-paths` parameter.

[image]

Another (non-GUI) way to turn warnings back on is to enter the equivalent command

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.housekeeping active true`

Comment: Great, This has led me to the answer I needed. In my case the "active" box was already checked but "/boot" was listed in the "ignore-paths". I have now removed it.

Comment: Good! For the sake of completeness, please allow me to add that to my answer.

Comment: Please do. I was hoping you would!